# AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1 not work

Tags: character-encoding, apache-httpd

I have upgrade Apache from 2.2 to 2.4 and I am having problems with character encoding. In my pages I have `è=Ã¨` `ò=Ã²` `ì=Ã¬` etc...

In my `httpd.conf` I have commented the default value and added `ISO-8859-1` (Western Europe)

```
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
```

But this didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP headers actually sent and the actual encoding of the pages? It seems that the pages are actually UTF-8 encoded, so they should be sent with UTF-8 specified as the encoding.

Comment: I had already checked: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Comment: OK, so the setting works. The problem is probably that the actual .html files are UTF-8 encoded. The Apache setting does not cause recoding; it only affects the HTTP headers.

Comment: But the files have not been changed and with Apache 2.2 and ISO-8859-1 everything worked perfectly, it all happened after switching to 2.4

Comment: Can you post an example URL?

Comment: I can post an image: http://i57.tinypic.com/kdww7k.png

Comment: The image confirms that the page contains UTF-8 encoded that is being misinterpreted as windows-1252 encoded (and browsers actually take iso-8859-1 as meaning windows-1252). Why this happens (and how the page can have worked before this) cannot be solved using the information disclosed. Perhaps the setting was somehow different (ineffectie due to some typo?) in Apache 2.2

Comment: is possibie that the error is also due to the changeover from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5?

Answer (score 10):

Are you running php? I think your problem is not in apache httpd.conf but in php.ini.

See this:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset
"In PHP 5.6 onwards, "UTF-8" is the default value and its value is used as the default character encoding ..."

Answer (score 4):

Those two different solutions worked for me :

1° Add this into the vhost:

```
php_value default_charset ISO-8859-1
```

2° Put

```
default_charset = "ISO-8859-1"
```

into `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (on Debian)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following option to your vhost config:

```
php_value default_charset ISO-8859-1
```